# Change single tap for execute to double tap

Tags: settings, touch

More often than not I accidentally execute a link in IE when all I wanted to do was to move the screen. Is it possible to make a double tap a requirement to open a link?

Comment: Does this happen for you only on specific websites?

Comment: I never have such a problem. I have no problem to move the page even when I hit links.

Comment: You mean that some websites are able to distinguish between one tap and one tap?

Comment: Try navigating www.zillow.com with your phone...

Comment: Works fine for me, so maybe your screen sensitivity settings. Of course, that site does have a Windows Phone app of their own, which may work better for you

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change single tap to double tap.

The problem that you are facing is very rare, probably you need to improve how you scroll and how you touch the screen.

**When you want to touch:** Gently put your finger on the screen for less than a second and then remove it.

**When you want to scroll:** Gently put your finger at any point on screen and than slide it down or up and than remove it from the screen.

The problem might also be with sensitivity of touch screen, if you think it is not sensitive enough, you can change sensitivity from **settings > touch > touch sensitivity**. You can set it to high.

Comment: Wouldn't accidentally tapping rather indicate touch sensitivity being too high already?

Comment: Well, I think because he is tapping in incorrect manner, links are invoked and not because of touch sensitivity. But only the OP can now tell us! :)

Comment: I do agree with that part of your answer :)